# How to get the last record from my table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am calling some data from my table in phpmyadmin and it duplicates the table for the amount of data that is in the one of phpmyadmin, and I only want the last data that is in my database

```
    </div>
      <?php

    $sql="SELECT * from roberto";
    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
     <table class="table is-striped is-narrow is-hoverable is-fullwidth">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Tipo</th>
      <th>Niveles</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>pH Sensor <spab></th>
      <td><p>Nivel de pH: <strong><span id="PHvalue"></span><?php echo $mostrar['nivelph']; ?></strong></p>  
      </td>
      <td>Funcionando</td>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Caudalímetro</th>
      <td><p><strong><?php echo $mostrar['caudal']; ?>10L/min</strong></p>
      </td>
      <td>Funcionando</td>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Bomba subir pH ↑</th>
      <td><span>""" + str(ph) + """pH</span>
      </td>
      <td>Subiendo el pH↑</td>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Bomba bajar pH ↓</th>
      <td><span>""" + str(ph) + """pH</span>
      </td>
      <td>Bajando el pH↓</td>
  </tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Nutrientes</th>
      <td><span>1mL/24horas</span>
      </td>
      <td>Activando bomba</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
</section>
<?php
}
?>
```

ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a MySQL administration tool written in PHP, it is not a database itself. You are probably using MySQL or MariaDB as your DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last of all the rows in the table, then this is answer:

```
SELECT * FROM roberto ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;

Answer (score -2):

this code brings the last id inserted in the database connection

```
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id($conn));
```

Comment: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: This returns the ID that was assigned during the last INSERT if the table has an AUTO_INCREMENT column. It's not useful for this question.

Comment: And the `mysql_XXX` functions are obsolete.

Answer (score -2):

this query get the lastg id of the conection
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: This returns the ID that was assigned during the last INSERT if the table has an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. It's not useful for this question.